# ¿Cómo obtener el Título de un vídeo de YouTube? "estoy utilizando iFrame"

Tags: javascript, iframe

Éste es mi código del iframe y su funcion js, donde cargo los vídeos, quisiera poder obtener el título del vídeo que se carga en el iframe, ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

```
<div>
<iframe id="browser" name="browser" src="http://static.betazeta.com/www.fayerwayer.com/up/2011/09/youtube-logo-650x350.jpg" scrolling="yes" height="350" width="650"></iframe>
<h3 class="text-danger">Ingresa Link</h3>
<br />
<form method="post" target="browser" runat="server">
<input id="txtUrl" style="width: 82%;" placeholder="Ingresa el link" name="url" type="text" class="form-control" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Probar" onclick="LinkYT(); "
class="btn blue button-next" />
<input id="btnLink" type="button" value="Agregar Enlace" class="btn blue button-next" />
</form>
<br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    debugger
    function LinkYT() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtUrl").value.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/') == "")
    { 
    alert("Ingrese un link"); 
    }
    else
    var browserFrame = document.getElementById("browser");
    browserFrame.src = document.getElementById("txtUrl").value.replace('watch?v=', 'embed/');
    return browserFrame.src;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando la  JavaScript API

```js
var loadInfo = function (videoId) {
    var gdata = document.createElement("script");
    gdata.src = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId + "?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=storeInfo";
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    body.appendChild(gdata);
};

var storeInfo = function (info) {
    console.log(info);
};

loadInfo()
```

solamente necesitas llamar :

```
 loadInfo(videoId)
```

Mas informacion aqui : [Documentacion](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json)

Igualmente puedes ver mas respuesta en esta pregunta de stackoverflow en ingles : 
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216029/get-title-from-youtube-videos)

Comment: Parece ser que la versión 2 de la API ya no está disponible.

Comment: asi :(  entonces que version se anda usando ahora